# Two way databinding not working on directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have a directive and I want to **change the ng-model value** given with this directive...
I'm setting `scope: {ngModel: '='}` and I'm changing the ngModel value (on click event) inside my directive but I can't see changes on my **external/original object**.

This [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZTOAyaayKCp7PDhqpvD) shows the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here, all of them common mistakes.

1. Event handlers registered through jQuery using `$(...).on(...)` will be executed outside of angular context, so angular will not know when things have updated. To address this, you must wrap the contents in a `scope.$apply` call like so

   ```
   $('#aaa').on('click', function() {
       _scope.$apply(function(){
           _scope.ngModel = 'Other Value';
           updateTemplate();
       });
   });
   ```

   This will update the binding to the input with `ng-model`. In fact you can avoid having to do this by using the [`ng-click`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angClick) directive.
2. With angular, you do not need to update templates like this yourself using `.html(...)`. Binding is one of the major features of the framework. Instead of having the update function, you can use interpolation by putting an expression inside of `{{ ... }}` and your DOM will be updated when your model is. For example when defining the directive you can use

   ```
   template: '<div id="aaa">{{ngModel}}</div>'
   ```

   to set your template and `{{ngModel}}` will show the current value of `ngModel`.
3. `ngModel` is not just any attribute, it is a powerful directive. If you need your own directive to be able to declare the current model valid or invalid, or to interact with forms then you should use this through the `require` property on your controller (see [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController)).

   If you don't need those features then you should be calling your attribute something different to avoid conflict.

I have updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TPg5bz?p=preview) to include these points.